# Synchronize on BlockedQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, findbugs, synchronized

I have a code piece that I am reviewing (using [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)).

```
public class MyClass{
...
private BlockedQueue q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<MyData>(1000);
private static final batchSize = 1000;

public boolean testMethod(){
    boolean done = false;
    synchronized(q){
       if(q.size == batchSize){
         q.notify();
         done = true;
       }
    }
    return done;
```

}

When I run FindBugs on this piece of code, it complains that -

> This method performs synchronization
>   an object that is an instance of a
>   class from the java.util.concurrent
>   package (or its subclasses). Instances
>   of these classes have there own
>   concurrency control mechanisms that
>   are distinct from and incompatible
>   with the use of the keyword
>   synchronized.

If I comment out the synchronized code piece `synchronized(q){`, it complains -

> This method calls Object.notify() or
>   Object.notifyAll() without obviously
>   holding a lock on the object.  Calling
>   notify() or notifyAll() without a lock
>   held will result in an
>   IllegalMonitorStateException being
>   thrown

How would I implement this method so that it passes FindBugs validation? Is the above implementation right one for notification in cases for concurrent classes?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `testMethod()` makes no sense by itself; there's got to be more to this story. As it is, the answer is "don't synchronize and don't call notify()".

Comment: Finding the size of a concurrent data structure doesn't make a great deal of sense anyway.

Comment: ChssPly76, Thank you. The testMethod() is just that, used to check the size, and invoke notify().
"tackline", I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notify()` goes together with `wait()` and should not be used with classes of `java.util.concurrent`.

BlockingQueue uses internal mechanisms to block on a `put()` if there is no space for more elements or on `poll()` if there is no element to consume. You don't have to care about this.

Comment: Nice follow up article for more insight: [Guide to java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](https://www.baeldung.com/java-blocking-queue)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is stating that you shouldn't use primitive synchronization controls on java.util.concurrent classes (like BlockingQueue).

Generally, this is good practice as they take care of the synchronization for you.  I'd imagine that there is a better way to solve your problem at hand.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

The second error is caused by the fact that you MUST own the lock/monitor of an object (by sychronizing on it) to call wait/notify/notifyAll on it

Comment: The problem I am trying to resolve is to ensure that FindBug does not report any error. The code is a marriage between concurrent classes and primitive synchronization. I would like to know what the best implementation is. As I said, I am "reviewing" the code, and looking at best possible implementation.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you're solving your problem in the wrong way, I'm just not sure what problem you're trying to solve.  Can you edit your initial post to provide your complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

BlockingQueue is a **syncronizer** object - coordinates the control flow of threads based on its state and thus control flow of producer/consumer threads because **take** and **put** block until the queue enters the desired state (not empty or not full).

Also good practice in concurrency programming assumes that wait and notify are placed in while loop.